# subscripting not working in R

Tags: r

I have this simple code and it is driving me nuts. The code is simply looping through a vector and subscripting parts of it.

```
preda <- function(d, k) {
  n <- length(d)
  cat("Length: ", n, "Loop:", k+1, "-", n, "\n")
  for(i in seq(from=k+1, to=n, by=1)) {
    cat("Index: ", i, "; Subscript Start: ", i-k, "; End: ", i-1, "\n")
    cat("Value: ", d[i-k:i-1], "\n") # on first loop, this should do 1:3
  }
}
```

The output

```
> X = sample(0:1,100,replace=T)
> preda(X, 3)
  Length:  100 Loop: 4 - 100
  Index:  4; Subscript Start:  1 End:  3
  #it doesn't subscript here.
  Value:  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  Index:  5 St:  2 En:  4
  Error in d[i - k:i - 1] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you're missing a closing curly brace `}` in your function (at least in the post)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to add in the post.

Comment: change this `d[i - k:i - 1]` to this `d[(i-k):(i-1)]`

Comment: That worked. I am pythonist, so I presumed it would work here as well.

Comment: This language is a little quirky :) I'll add as an answer. I'd recommend you take a look ad Hadley Wickham's advanced R, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ could be useful

Comment: you fell into circle 8.1.3 of the [r inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are having problems with the colon operator (`:`). Swithcing to `d[(i-k):(i-1)]` will solve the issue:

```
#> preda(X,3)
#Length:  100 Loop: 4 - 100 
#Index:  4 ; Subscript Start:  1 ; End:  3 
#Value:  0 0 0 
#Index:  5 ; Subscript Start:  2 ; End:  4 
#Value:  0 0 1 
#...
```

Remember that the colon operator (see `help(":")`) needs two arguments (`a` and `b`) so a parenthesis will keep things tidy.